# ¿Cómo verificar que el correo electrónico sea auténtico en Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-auth

Necesito añadir a mi código actual, la funcionalidad necesaria y el código exacto para que el usuario deba verificar el email antes de iniciar sesión.

Ahora, el usuario se registra y automáticamente accede a todas las funciones de la aplicación y de su panel de usuario.
Quiero agregar la función necesaria para que cuando un usuario se registre, se le muestre un mensaje diciéndole que :
***Debe verificar su email***
De este modo nos aseguramos que es un correo válido y evitar el registro de usuarios SPA.

Necesito que el usuario verifique su correo electrónico para para poder iniciar sesión, hasta que no lo haga, podrá seguir usando la App como lo hacia, sin iniciar sesión.

Pueden ver que hice varias pruebas, y otros usuarios trataron de ayudarme, pero no hemos conseguido lo necesario, ***ya que necesito añadir la funcionalidad al código que tengo ahora, pues es la única forma que se de seguir construyendo mi aplicación.***

La aplicación tiene el registro con `Firebase`, registrado por correo electrónico y contraseña y estoy usando `Formik` para controlar el estado del formulario y `Yup` para validar.

He leído la documentación de `Firebase` sobre [Enviar un mensaje de verificación a un usuario](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)

Esta es la función de `Firebase`:

```
const auth = getAuth();
sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
  .then(() => {
    // Email verification sent!
    // ...
  })
```

El sistema de registro que uso ahora es Correo y Contraseña. El usuario ingresa un correo electrónico, una contraseña, verifica la contraseña y automáticamente se registra en la aplicación.

Hice varias pruebas tratando de agregar `sendEmailVerification` a mi sistema de registro, y por ahora lo que he logrado es que el correo electrónico de confirmación llega al usuario (carpeta SPA) pero el correo electrónico de confirmación llega después de que el usuario ya se registró y usa la aplicación.

***Sería necesario que el usuario no pudiera registrarse hasta recibir y confirmar el "Correo electrónico de confirmación"***

***Necesito un ejemplo de código que se adapte a mi app actual, no tengo conocimientos para cambiar todo mi código, esta es la base de mi app.***

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que esto funcione correctamente y llegue el correo de verificación antes de que el usuario pueda restar registrado?

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en mi código?

Puede probar el proyecto tal como está construido con Expo:

`exp://exp.host/@miguelitolaparra/restaurantes-5-estrellas?release-channel=default`

[image: codi QR para aplicación en Expo]

Este es el método que estoy usando para registrar usuarios:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues(),
    validationSchema: validationSchema(), // validate the form data
    validateOnChange: false,
    onSubmit: async(formValue) => {
      try { // send the data to Firebase
        const auth = getAuth()
       // sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
        await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          formValue.email,
          formValue.password
        )
      
       sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)

        navigation.navigate(screen.account.account)
      } catch (error) {
        // We use Toast to display errors to the user
        Toast.show({
          type: "error",
          position: "bottom",
          text1: "Failed to register, please try again later",
        })
      }
    },
  })
```

Y también os muestro el archivo completo:

```
    import { useFormik } from 'formik'
    
    import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendEmailVerification } from 'firebase/auth'
    
    export function RegisterForm() {
      const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
      const [showRepeatPassword, setShowRepeatPassword] = useState(false)
    
      const navigation = useNavigation()
    
      const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: initialValues(),
        validationSchema: validationSchema(), // validate the form data
        validateOnChange: false,
        onSubmit: async (formValue) => {
          try { // send the data to Firebase
            const auth = getAuth()
            //sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              auth,
              formValue.email,
              formValue.password
            )
          sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
    
           
            navigation.navigate(screen.account.account)
          } catch (error) {
            // We use Toast to display errors to the user
            Toast.show({
              type: "error",
              position: "bottom",
              text1: "Error al registrarse, intentelo mas tarde",
            })
          }
        },
      })
    
      // function to hide or show the password
      const showHidenPassword = () => setShowPassword((prevState) => !prevState)
      const showHidenRepeatPassword = () => setShowRepeatPassword((prevState) => !prevState)
    
      return (
        // Registration form interface
        <View>
          <Input
            placeholder="Correo electronico"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            containerStyle={AuthStyles.input}
            rightIcon={
              <Icon type="material-community" name="at" iconStyle={AuthStyles.icon} />
            }
            onChangeText={(text) => formik.setFieldValue("email", text)}
            errorMessage={formik.errors.email}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="Contraseña"
            containerStyle={AuthStyles.input}
            secureTextEntry={showPassword ? false : true}
            rightIcon={
              <Icon
                type="material-community"
                name={showPassword ? "eye-off-outline" : "eye-outline"}
                iconStyle={AuthStyles.icon}
                onPress={showHidenPassword}
              />
            }
            onChangeText={(text) => formik.setFieldValue("password", text)}
            errorMessage={formik.errors.password}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="Repetir contraseña"
            containerStyle={AuthStyles.input}
            secureTextEntry={showRepeatPassword ? false : true}
            rightIcon={
              <Icon
                type="material-community"
                name={showRepeatPassword ? "eye-off-outline" : "eye-outline"}
                iconStyle={AuthStyles.icon}
                onPress={showHidenRepeatPassword}
              />
            }
            onChangeText={(text) => formik.setFieldValue("repeatPassword", text)}
            errorMessage={formik.errors.repeatPassword}
          />
          <Button
            title="REGISTRATE"
            containerStyle={AuthStyles.btnContainer}
            buttonStyle={AuthStyles.btn}
            onPress={formik.handleSubmit} // send the form
            loading={formik.isSubmitting}// show loading while doing user registration
          />
        </View>
      )
    }
```

Y este es el archivo para validar el formulario con `Yup`
Validar.js

```
    import * as Yup from "yup"
    
    // object that has the elements of the form
    export function initialValues() {
      return {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        repeatPassword: "",
      }
    }
    
    // validate the form data whit Yup
    export function validationSchema() {
      return Yup.object({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email("El email no es correcto")
          .required("El email es obligatorio"),
        password: Yup.string().required("La contraseña es obligatoria"),
      
        repeatPassword: Yup.string()  // validate that the passwords are the same
          .required("La contraseña es obligatoria")
          .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Las contraseñas tienen que ser iguales"),
      })
    }
```

Comment: Generalmente, los pasos son: 1. El usuario se registra con su dirección de correo electrónico. 2. Se crea el nuevo registro, pero con estado "Por verificar" y se asigna una cadena de activación. 3. Envías datos de usuario y cadena de activación, junto con enlace para verificar registro. 4. El usuario hace clic en el enlace, coloca sus datos y, si son válidos, cambias el estado a "Activo".

Comment: Gracias @Triby por tu comentario. El registro me funciono perfectamente, y queria conservar este tipo de registro, me costo dias hacerlo. Luego al hacer pruebas, vi la parte mala de esto, que podias usrar cualquier cadena de texto para registrarte, con los inconvenientes que esto supone. No se por donde seguir, me has dejado bloqueado. No se que hacer para conseguir todo lo que dices

Answer (score 1):

imagino que Inicializo Cloud Firestore y obtiene una referencia al servicio

Autenticación te vas **settings** da click dominios autorizados, luego al botón agregar un dominio

voy a dejar este link explique  como inicializar Cloud Firestore si lo necesitan  [Resolver la conexión a base de datos de firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/550122/resolver-la-conexi%c3%b3n-a-base-de-datos-de-firebase/550145#550145)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Template** debe dar click en la flecha señalada y agregas el path junto con los params ?mode=action&oobCode=code, donde quiere que redireccione una vez llegue el correo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que creamos la cuenta comprendemos user.emailVerified === false, enviara una verificación al correo, ten en cuenta que al mismo tiempo se hace logout, esto en mi caso lo hice porque una vez validada la cuenta  y redireccionaba a home no cargaba el estado actual y tenia que recargar para que sea user.emailVerified === true , de este modo en mi caso lo redireccione despues de validar a login

```
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  getAuth,
  sendEmailVerification,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

    const formik = useFormik({
      initialValues: initialValues(),
      validationSchema: validationSchema(),
      validateOnChange: false,
    
      onSubmit: async ({ email, password }) => {
        try {
          // send the data to Firebase
          const auth = getAuth();
    
          createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
            async ({ user }) => {
    
              if (user.emailVerified === false) {
                sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser).then(async () => {
                  await signOut(auth);
                });
              }
              
            }
          );
    
        } catch (error) {
          Toast.show({
            type: "error",
            position: "bottom",
            text1: "Failed to register, please try again later",
          });
        }
      },
    });
```

una vez que llegue el correo si no revisa **spam** haz click en el enlace para que te redireccione el sitio, hay debes tener dos botones uno para **validar** y otro para enviar a **login** , para validar debe tener una accion, algo muy importante debes recuperar params **oobCode** es lo que te permite autenticar el correo

```
  const handleVerify = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await applyActionCode(auth, actionCode)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("verificado")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // error
    });

  };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por mostrar interés en mi recompensa @JacksonQuintero, pero no veo la forma de añadir tu propuesta a mi App. Revisa la pregunta y la aclaración cuando ofreci la recompensa. Por ahora tu respuesta no cumple, ya que yo no tengo la forma de añadir tu ejemplo a mi archivo. Dame un ejemplo claro, que pueda utilizar y funcione, y puedo aceptarla. Lo que me muestras por el momento, ya lo he visto yo en [la documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/email-custom-domain)

Comment: lo cambie a la version 9 intenta  espero que sea tu solucion

Comment: cualquier cosa me dice hasta donde le funciona por favor

Comment: Gracias, ¿ donde debo añadir exactamente el segundo fragmento de código que me muestra en su respuesta ?

 `const handleVerify = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await applyActionCode(auth, actionCode)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("verificado")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // error
    })

  }` No consigo que funcione, ni hace el registro, y tampoco llega el correro de verificación

Comment: Parece que funciona, pero es necesario que sea obligatorio verificar el email. Ahora el usuario se registra y no se loguea directamente, pero si me registro con un email falso, después de hacer el registro puedo acceder a la aplicación desde login sin  problema. La verificación debe ser obligatoria, y no permitir el acceso a la  App hasta que el usuario verifique su correo. puede verlo usted mismo. Necesito mostrar al usuario que debe revisar su correo para verificar el correo electrónico, ahora esto tampoco se muestra al usuario https://expo.dev/@miguelitolaparra/grandres-empresas

Comment: con respecto al primer párrafo que coloco lo que tiene que hacer, crea un pequeño formulario como en la ultima foto que le envie y  le agrega  onSubmit={handleVerify} y lo envia , o crear un  boton que active la funcion ,

Comment: A ver,   no necesito más formularios, ya tengo un formulario de registro que funciona perfectamente. Ahora yo no se como crear otro formulario. No se preocupe, ya buscare solución de otra forma. Le agradezco su trabajo, pero como dige en la pregunta, necesito un ejemplo practico y funcional, no modificar toda mi App. Seguire buscando otras opciones. Me centrare en otras respuestas que puedan dar.

Comment: con respeto al segundo párrafo que envió si tiene persistente onAuthStateChanged le puede agregar una validación  user.emailVerified === false  logout si no continua  tambien lo puede agregar cuando inicia seccion

Comment: no estoy diciendo que haga otro formulario amigo es de guia  para que lo hagas como esta haciendo, ya me meti en formulario e hize login , no tiene que redireccionar a ningun lado una vez que hagas logout

Comment: No debes preocuparte más, buscare otras opciones, tu idea es complicada y unicamente me dices lo que debo hacer, pero yo no se hacerlo, por ello vine aquí a preguntar y explico lo que busco en la pregunta. Ahora no quiero hacer una app nueva, ya lo tengo construido y la pregunta explica claramente lo que necesito. Ya hice experimentos con tus ideas, pero no puedo seguir, no tengo capacidad para realizar lo que dices, necesito cosas claras. Estoy muy agradecido. Seguire buscando ideas

Comment: ok esta bien comprendo, bueno  son cosas que e implementado en mis proyecto funciona bien, cualquier cosa si no consigue lograrlo me escribe  podría revisar tu código y hacerlo funcional

Comment: @MiguelEspeso, por el tono de tus palabras, pareciera que has contratado a Jackson para resolver tu problema, pero no creo que 200 puntos de reputación sean suficientes para dirigirte a él en esa forma, de hecho, aunque hubiera un pago de por medio el trato debería ser mucho más cordial.

Comment: No se que imagina usted @Triby, personalmente estoy agradecido hacia este señor que voluntariamente y dedicando parte de su tiempo esta tratando de ayudarme para que consiga mis necesidades.  Unicamente he tratado de comunicarle que puede hacer lo que crea necesario en la pregunta para que funcione. No se, quiza en adelante deba de medir mis palabras, pero ya digo que lo unico que he querido demostrar es agradecimiento y hacia la generosidad de este hombre conmigo.

Comment: He seguido haciendo pruebas con tus aportes pero no he conseguido mi propósito. Aún asi, te otorgue los puntos de la recompensa ya que hiciste mucho esfuerzo para ayudarme. Muchas gracias @JacksonQuintero

Answer (score 0):

Ahí veo que vos tenés

```
   const auth = getAuth();
```

En algún lado tienes que tener una constante con la información para conectarte a firebase:

```
//configuración    
const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: firebaseConf.API_KEY,
        authDomain: firebaseConf.AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: firebaseConf.PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: firebaseConf.STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: firebaseConf.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: firebaseConf.APP_ID
    };
```

Con esa constante se inicializa otra constante:

```
// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

y con esa inicializamos auth:

```
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

ese auth ya sabe que estas autorizado para usar la sección auth de firebase y todo lo que tenga que ver con autentificación de usuarios vas a usar ese auth.

Cuando se crea un usuario, si se crea satisfactoriamente, firebase te devuelve una credencial.

```
     const credential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                               auth, 
                               formValue.email, 
                               formValue.password
                                );
```

Esa credencial es la misma que te devuelve cuando el usuario ingresa con su email y password. Esta, tiene mucha información, entre ella, tiene un objeto user: que dentro tiene entre otras la propiedad emailVerified: que puede ser true (si está verificado) o false (si no no está verificado), una vez que tengo la credencial, mando la verificación

```
sendEmailVerification(credential.user)
                      .then(() => console.log('envio de verificacion'))
                      .catch(() => console.log('La verificacion no fue enviada'));
```

esto le va a enviar al usuario un email para que haga click en un link, eso le va a decir a firebase que la propiedad de user:{emailVerified:true}

Tu estrategia cuando alguien ingresa debería ser algo asi:

- Por un lado tenés el registro del nuevo usuario en REGISTRATE, donde crea la nueva cuenta, y envia la verificación al email, en esta sección no lo dejas entrar le mostrás un cartel que diga, verifique su correo en el con el link que le enviamos. Le sacas el navigation.navigate(screen.account.account).
- Por el otro tenés el ingreso del usuario ya registrado en INGRESE, donde hay un formulario donde el usuario ingresa su email y su password,este formulario tiene que tener un handlesubmit (la función a don de se va cuando uno hace click en enviar ) en la mima va a haber un código como este:

  ```
   const credential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user, password);
       if(credential.user.emailVerified){
              //algorimo para dejar pasar al usuairo...
              navigation.navigate(screen.account.account);
              console.log('Bienvenido');
       }else{

          Toast.show({
                  type: "error",
                  position: "bottom",
                  text1: "Debe verificar su cuenta para poder ingresar, verifique que el mail que le enviamos no este en spam y haga click en el link de verificacion",
                })


        }
  ```

Esa es la forma práctica que veo para resolver ese problema

Eso es todo, espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias amigo @SergioAntozzi. Esta bien explicado, pero no termina de funcionar. He añadido el fragmento de código este `sendEmailVerification(credential.user)...`, y la primera vez envio el correo de verificación, pero he seguido probando, y en ocasiones posteriores el usuario se registra automaticamente sin necesidad de verificar el correo, como me ocurría a mi. Incluso ya no envia ni el correo de verificación, lo hizo la primera vez, y no volvio. ¿ Tienes alguna idea de  como puedo añadirlo o que código,  y donde debo añadirlo ? Seguire haciendo pruebas a la espera de tus palabras me guien

Comment: Por cierto, esta parte del ejemplo, no funciona, no se muestran los `console.log()`: 
Esto no se muestra en consola:
 `.then(() => console.log('envio de verificacion'))
 .catch(() => console.log('La verificacion no fue enviada'))`

Comment: si no entro en los logs, es que no esta entrando, se me hace que no estas obteniendo la credencial, fijate que dice await adelante, para que funcione eso tenes que tener en la funcion dende lo ejecutas async, lo tenes?

Comment: proba haciendo console.log(credential) justo despues de obtenerla, si te aparece undefined es que te falta meter el async, si no sale, probalo un par de veces mas, y si en todas sale el log de la credencial es otro el problema

Comment: He añadido el fragmento 6 y 7 de tu respuesta y en consola recibo: `envio de verificacion` .  Añadiendo el `console.log(credential)`, recibo el token y mucha información, parece que toso funciona. Pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo que hasta ahora, el correo de verificación llega al usuario, y tambien se registra automáticamente cuando toca el botón de **"REGISTRATE"**. Yo necesito que el usuario después de realizar el registro, deba confirmar el correo antes de poder estar logueado. Unicamente queda por añadir el ultimo fragmento de código de tu respuesta, no se donde hacerlo.

Comment: Modifiqué la publicación no se si te llega el mensaje.

Comment: Gracias por tu dedicación @SergioAntozzi. Modifique el código igual que hizo usted y todo sigue igual, incluso recibo algún error en consola: `An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: auth] in submitForm._catch$argument_0` El registro se realiza, pero como hasta ahora, directamente el usuario se muestra registrado al enviar el **REGISTRATE** Empiezo a pensar que puede ser que yo estoy haciendo las cosas mal. ¿ Puedes modificar tu respuesta añadiendo tu código a el código de mi pregunta y mostrando como quedaría exactamente el archivo final?